# resizableImage for UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios5

I am working for IOS 5.0 as minTarget

I have a UIImageView to which i want to assign a resizable image, so that image don't get stretch from corners.

i have tried setting content mode of UIImageView to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill. But the image appears as tiled.

here's the code

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImgViewBg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)];

imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
imgView.image = bgImage;
```

I am looking for the same effect as we have with 9patch images in android

here's the image i am trying on
[image: ImgViewBg]

I just gave an another look at the documentation of resizeableImageWithCapInsets. It says it tiles the the area which is not under cap. I think that what causing the tiled pattern. Is there any workaround to this so that i can have 9Patch style image??

## EDIT

According to Apple Docs
upto IOS 5.0 following works for my req.
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textViewBg"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6];
(as mentioned by Dipen Panchasara)

IOS6.0 and later following works for my req.
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode

IOS 5.0 and later (which i required)
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
above function does not work in my case, as it tiles the image not under cap.

so for IOS 5.0 to IOS 6.0 i was not able to find anything which solves my requirement.

For now i moving to use Dipen Panchasara solution, i hope it stays stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Use following code to make stretchableBackground
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImgViewBg"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:13];
[imgView setImage:bgImage];
```

Comment: it's depreciated in ios5.0

Answer (score 0):

ScaleToFill will stretch the image to fill the entire image view. If you don't want to stretch the image and maintain it's aspect ratio, use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit OR UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

You can find more information about these constants [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Comment: i am not worried about the aspect ratio. i have rounded corners in image which i want to preserve.